# Matrices and Divisibility

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $T_p$ be the following set of $2$ x $2$ matrices
$$T_p=\{A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ c & a \end{array}\right); a,b,c \in\{0,1,2,3...,p-1\}\}$$
 **Q.1) The no. of $A$ in $T_p$ such that $det(A)$ is not divisible by p.**

(A) $2p^2$

(B) $p^3-5p$

(C) $p^3-3p$

(D) $p^3 - p^2$

**Q.2) The no. of $A$ in $T_p$ such that the trace of $A$ is not divisible by $p$ but $det(A)$ is divisible by $p$**

(A) $(p-1)(p^2-p+1)$

(B) $p^3-(p-1)^2$

(C) $(p-1)^2$

(D) $(p-1)(p^2-2)$

**Q.3) The no. of $A$ in $T_p$ such that $A$ is either symmetric or skew-symmetric or both and $det(A)$ is divisible by $p$**

(A) $(p-1)^2$

(B) $2(p-1)$

(C) $(p-1)^2 +1$

(D) $2p-1$

I wa able to solve Q.3 only.

Approach:-

Considering the values of $a,b,c,$ $A$ can never be skew-symmetric.

Now $det(A) = a^2-bc$

For symmetric matrix, $b=c$

So, $det(A)=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

**Case $I$**: $a=b$

There are $p$ ways of selecting $a$ or $b$ (Select any no. in $\{1,2,3...,p-1\}$

**Case $II$**: $a \neq b$

$a+b$ must be a multiple of $p$ since $a-b$ will always given a no. less than $p$ according to the given set of $a,b,c$ and also $p$ is a prime no.

So there are $p-1$ ways to select $a$ and $b$.

Possible ordered pairs of $(a,b)$ $(1,p-1), (2,p-2),...(p-1,1)$

Total ways: $2p-1$

Need help for Q.1 and Q.2

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry for typo. I have corrected it now.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this question, and for solving it we require that $a^2=bc$. I could not find the number of ways in which this can be done and I put it up as a question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279453/square-of-number-expressed-as-the-product-of-two-other-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1  . So I think there must be some mistake in this question.

Comment: @AnanthKamath I don't think so that there is any mistake as it is a question from JEE 2010 paper

Comment: I've seenthe question myself and searched for solutions in MTG question bank as well as Resonance solution to that paper. Neither gave any plausible explanation. Resonance did not give any explanation at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are

Q1:  $ \ p^3-p^2$,

Q2:  $ \ (p-1)^2$.

To obtain these answers, let us solve an auxiliary problem first:

**How many combinations of $a,b,c\in[0,p-1]$ result in $\det A$ divisible by $p$?**

**Example $1$:** $ \ p=3. \ $ We have only $p^2=9$ combinations with $\det A$ divisible by $p$, namely:
$$
a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=0 \\
a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=1 \\
a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=2 \\
a=0, \quad b=1, \quad c=0 \\
a=0, \quad b=2, \quad c=0 \\
a=1, \quad b=1, \quad c=1 \\
a=1, \quad b=2, \quad c=2 \\
a=2, \quad b=1, \quad c=1 \\
a=2, \quad b=2, \quad c=2 \\
$$
Of these, $(p-1)^2=4$ combinations have $a\ne0$, 
and $2p-1=5$ combinations have $a=0$. Indeed,
$$
(p-1)^2 + (2p-1) = p^2.
$$

**Example $2$:**  $ \ p=5. \ $ We have $p^2=25$ combinations with $\det A$ divisible by $p$. Similar to the previous example, $(p-1)^2=16$ combinations have $a\ne0$, 
and $2p-1=9$ combinations have $a=0$. 
Here are all the combinations with $p\,|\,\det A\,$ for $p=5$:
$$
 a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=0 \\
 a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=1 \\
 a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=2 \\
 a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=3 \\
 a=0, \quad b=0, \quad c=4 \\
 a=0, \quad b=1, \quad c=0 \\
 a=0, \quad b=2, \quad c=0 \\
 a=0, \quad b=3, \quad c=0 \\
 a=0, \quad b=4, \quad c=0 \\
 a=1, \quad b=1, \quad c=1 \\
 a=1, \quad b=2, \quad c=3 \\
 a=1, \quad b=3, \quad c=2 \\
 a=1, \quad b=4, \quad c=4 \\
 a=2, \quad b=1, \quad c=4 \\
 a=2, \quad b=2, \quad c=2 \\
 a=2, \quad b=3, \quad c=3 \\
 a=2, \quad b=4, \quad c=1 \\
 a=3, \quad b=1, \quad c=4 \\
 a=3, \quad b=2, \quad c=2 \\
 a=3, \quad b=3, \quad c=3 \\
 a=3, \quad b=4, \quad c=1 \\
 a=4, \quad b=1, \quad c=1 \\
 a=4, \quad b=2, \quad c=3 \\
 a=4, \quad b=3, \quad c=2 \\
 a=4, \quad b=4, \quad c=4. \\
$$

This pattern holds in the general case; there are $p^2$ combinations with
$p\,|\,\det A$, namely:

- Each $a\in[1,p-1]$ corresponds to 
  $(p-1)$ combinations with $\det A$ divisible by $p$. This gives us $(p-1)^2$
  combinations with $p\,|\,\det A$ and $a\ne0$.
- In addition, there are also $2p-1$ different combinations where $p\,|\,\det A$ and $a=0$.

**Now it is easy to answer Questions 1 and 2**

**Question 1:** There are $p^3$ combinations altogether. Of these, $p^2$ combinations correspond to $\det A$ divisible by $p$. Hence there are $p^3-p^2$ combinations with $\det A$ not divisible by $p$.

**Question 2:** We easily see that the trace of $A$ (which is $2a$) is divisible by $p$ if and only if $a=0$. So out of $p^2$ combinations where $p\,|\,\det A$ we need to exclude the $(2p-1)$ combinations where $a=0$. This leaves us with 
$$
p^2 - (2p-1) = (p-1)^2
$$
combinations where $a\ne0$ and $p\not|\,\,{\rm tr}\, A$ while $p\,|\,\det A$.